# Why does the "Logon Help" dialog show up on every boot?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

Every time I boot Windows XP Professional on my notebook, the *Logon Help* dialog (the one which tells you how to press Ctrl-Alt-Delete) automatically opens. How do I disable this?

This did not always happen, but has been going on for quite a while now, with both SP2 and SP3. I'm using the classic logon screen, where you have to type in your username and password.

[image: Logon Help dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Normally that comes up if keys are pressed or held down too long.  Is it possible you have a stuck key?

Comment: I didn't notice anything in that direction. Keyboard operation is absolutely normal after login.

Answer (score 0):

Just go in Control Panel->User Accounts  and delete the ASP.Net local account

This is an account that is used by asp debugger but is not required

Comment: I can't imagine what the existence of a certain user account has to do with a help dialog opening automatically. But since we're talking about Windows here, I tried disabling the account, didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can find is to go to Control Panel > User Accounts, and "Change the way users log on or off" and see if that works.

Comment: I can't find that option on my installation. Do you mean the "require users to press Ctrl-Alt-Delete" checkbox? I can't turn that off, seems to be a policy setting.